# Angular 6 Reactive Forms input type = “radio” mutually exclusive selection

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I have Angular Dynamic form where I will be loading data from a service. For the purpose of demo values are hard coded in the component.
I have checkboxes and radio buttons. The checkboxes functionality is fine. However, with radio buttons there are two issues:
1)  They are not mutually exclusive – not acting as a part of radiogroup. If I  add name property in HTML, dev tools throw error “If you define both a name and a formControlName attribute on your radio button, their values
      must match. Ex: ”.
So I guess it doesn’t work that way in reactive forms.
2)  I need to be able to go back and forth from this form (like a wizard) and the form should retain values. But only the check boxes are retaining values but not the radio buttons. For the purpose of demo, there is a save button, which is saving values to data.service class and the ‘Reload last save’ is mimicking the functionality in case we need to go back and forth and retrieves data from data.service

Please guide!
Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="processDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" *ngIf="isFormReady">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 margin-bottom" formArrayName='ContactStreamEntries'
                 *ngFor="let HCS of processDetailsForm.controls.ContactStreamEntries.controls; let i = index">
                <input [formControlName]="i" type="radio" name="ContactStreamEntries[i].HCS"
                        [checked]="(i === 0)"
                        [value]="ContactStreamEntries.HCS_ID"
                       (change)="onSelectionChange(entry)"
                       /> {{ContactStreamEntries[i].HCS}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 margin-bottom" formArrayName='ContactStreamsGroups'
                 *ngFor="let name of processDetailsForm.controls.ContactStreamsGroups.controls; let i = index">
                <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" /> {{ContactStreamsGroups[i].name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" id="btnNext"
                    [disabled]="processDetailsForm.invalid">
                save
            </button>
            <button type="submit" id="btnNext" (click)="ReloadProcessDetails()">
                Reload last save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reports',
    templateUrl: './reports.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./reports.component.scss']
})
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit {
    processDetailsForm: FormGroup;
    isFormReady: boolean = false;
    private selectedAssets;
    //private selectedGroups;
    public dataProcessDetail;
     ContactStreamsGroups = [
         { id: 1, name: 'Group 1' },
         { id: 2, name: 'Group 2' },
         { id: 3, name: 'Group 3' }
     ];
    ContactStreamEntries = [
        { HCS_ID: 1, HCS: 'ABC' },
        { HCS_ID: 2, HCS: 'DEF' }
    ];
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _dataService: DataService,
         private _router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.LoadControls();
        if (this._dataService.getBtnOption() === 'Back') {
            this.ReloadProcessDetails();
        }
    }
    submit() {
        this.selectedAssets = this.processDetailsForm.value;
        this.dataProcessDetail = {
            'selectedAssets': this.selectedAssets
        }
        this._dataService.setBtnOption('btnNextORBack', 'Next');

        this._dataService.setOptionProcessDetails('dataProcessDetail', this.dataProcessDetail);
        this._router.navigate(['forms']);
    }
    ReloadProcessDetails() {
        this.dataProcessDetail = this._dataService.getOptionProcessDetails();
        this.processDetailsForm.patchValue(this.dataProcessDetail.selectedAssets);
    }
    LoadControls() {
        const controlGroup = this.ContactStreamsGroups.map(c => new FormControl(false));
        const CS = this.ContactStreamEntries.map(c => new FormControl(false));

        this.processDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ContactStreamsGroups: new FormArray(controlGroup),
            ContactStreamEntries: new FormArray(CS)
        });
        this.isFormReady = true;

    }
}
```

Service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  public btnData: string;
  public processData: any = null;

  setOptionProcessDetails(option, value) {
    this.processData = value;
  }
  getOptionProcessDetails() {
    return this.processData;
  }
  setBtnOption(option, value) {
    this.btnData = value;
  }
  getBtnOption() {
    return this.btnData;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to give each radio button the same `formControlName` attribute to be part of the same group. Its value should be the name of one of the properties on your formGroup. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-su2vi7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Alex, P.S. I am not sure if you added relevant code in the stackblitz you created.

Comment: changed to input [formControlName]="i" type="radio" name="ContactStreamEntries[i].HCS", but still throws same error- "RROR Error: 
      If you define both a name and a formControlName attribute on your radio button, their values
      must match. Ex: <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food">"

Comment: Sorry, I goofed up the stackblitz! I'm getting confused by the data structure for your form. The user needs to choose one option for ContactStreamEntries, correct?

Comment: correct- that data ContactStreamEntries  is fed to dynamic radio buttons, ContactStreamsGroups  is for checkboxes

Comment: Maybe Stackblitz will work this time: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-su2vi7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html